# Android URI explanation for camera capture

Tags: java, android

Can anyone explain the following codes to me ?

```
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdDirectory);

        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);


        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
```

Comment: What **specifically** do you not understand?

Comment: explanation is given but always visit android documentation for these purpose!!

Comment: the 3rd line , why to we use it?

Answer (score 1):

**line 1-** 
Creates a Uri from a file. The URI has the form "file://". Encodes path characters with the exception of '/'.
Example: "file:///tmp/android.txt"

**Line 2-** Standard Intent action that can be sent to have the camera application capture an image and return it.

**Line 3-** Add extended data to the intent.

**Line 4-**

Sometimes you want to get a result back from an activity when it ends. For example, you may start an activity that lets the user pick a person in a list of contacts; when it ends, it returns the person that was selected. To do this, you call the startActivityForResult(Intent, int) version with a second integer parameter identifying the call. The result will come back through your onActivityResult(int, int, Intent) method.

Comment: Thank u for explaining in details

Comment: why is it important to use the 3rd line ??